# NMinimize extremely slow for simple, non-oscillatory function on an interval

Tags: mathematical-optimization

The minimum of $f(x) = -(x+1/2 \sqrt{1-x})$ for $x$ between $0$ and $1$ occurs at $x=15/16$ with $f(15/16)=-17/16$. This is a function that Mathematica evaluates quickly, and I have plotted the function and its minimum values below:

[image: Mathematica plot of function f]

Mathematica quickly evaluates

```
Minimize[{-x - 1/2 Sqrt[1 - x] , x > 0, x < 1}, x]
```

but is extremely slow in evaluating

```
NMinimize[{-x - 1/2 Sqrt[1 - x] , x > 0, x < 1}, x]
```

(In fact, Mathematica appears to hang when I try to evaluate the above.)

Why is this and how can I speed up the evaluation? Is it the way I specified the bounds? I have in mind somewhat more complicated examples but I'm hoping to understand this simple example first. I'm running 12.0 Student Edition on Windows 10.

Comment: On my installation (MM 12.1 on MacOS), both commands run effectively instantaneously, with the latter returning `{-1.0625, {x -> 0.9375}}` as expected.  So this may be a version-dependent bug.

Comment: Try this comparison on a fresh kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Method->"DifferentialEvolution"` option helps: compare

```
Minimize[{-x - 1/2 Sqrt[1 - x], x > 0, x < 1}, x] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.287915, {-(17/16), {x -> 15/16}}}`

with

```
NMinimize[{-x - 1/2 Sqrt[1 - x], x > 0, x < 1}, x, 
Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.116188, {-1.0625, {x -> 0.9375}}}`

and with

```
NMinimize[{-x - 1/2 Sqrt[1 - x], x > 0, x < 1}, x] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `0.298761, {-1.0625, {x -> 0.9375}}}`

Comment: The above is done in 12.3.1 on Windows 10. Though the `NMinimize` command was updated in 12.3, but its parts related to `Method`s weren't up to the documentation.

Comment: The difference is night and day on my installation - it finishes running when implementing the method you recommended, so this solves my problem.